# raise window underneath the current active one

Tags: macos

I am wondering is there a shortcut to raise another app's window underneath the current app's active one, so i can quickly toggle the top two windows, as this is a common workflow in my daily work.

I have tried a few window management apps, but couldn't find any that allows me to do this task.

I want to bring the window upfront immediately, not something like <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> that goes through a list of all open windows.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've reopened your question for now (but it's likely there's another duplicate somewhere and may need to be closed again). However, I wanted to take the time to comment on these words: *not something like cmd + tab to go through a list of windows*.  You can in fact use cmd + tab to quickly cycle between the two most recent apps. That is, press the combination once quickly and it'll take you to the last app used (and its foremost window), so there's no need to toggle through the rest of the list. Therefore, I'm pretty sure that user3439894's answer will meet your needs.

Comment: yes, thanks for your comment, cmd + tab works very well.

Answer (score 2):

If the window you want to raise belongs to the active app of the frontmost window, then you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> to bring the next window forward.

You can then use <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> to bring back the previous window. (This combo also walks backwards through the apps windows.)

---

If the window you want to raise does not belong to the active app, but a different app altogether you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> and then <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> again to get back to the previous app, assuming it hasn't been closed.

<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> can be used to walk backwards in the app switcher.

---

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> is the command key.
- <kbd>`</kbd> is the Grave Accent, and on a US keyboard is just above the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.
- <kbd>⇧</kbd> is the shift key,